# Term for user interfaces using characters to create "keyboard navigating menus": GUI or CLI?

Tags: terminology, gui, user-interface

Does anyone know a term for these kind of user interfaces? Some examples:

- old BIOS menu of PCs
- safeboot menu of windows
- other old MSDOS applications running on fullscreen using "keyboard navigating menus" (like accounting softwares).

What is the technical term for such types of interfaces? This could be helpful when searching on google (keywords) for information on writing such applications.

Comment: I took the freedom and edited your question heavily. Please double check if I got your intentions right.

Comment: Yes, it is now perfect. And very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you are looking for is [**Text-based user interface**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface) (TUI). Wikipedia has also some links to libraries which can be used to create such interfaces.